# Are there musical terms like linguistic terms n-gram or uni-gram and bi-gram?

Tags: harmony

I don't know if there is anything else to add to my question except the context is harmony...

`V7-I` or `Gr+6-V` etc. would be a bi-grams.

`I-(IV6)-I` could be considered a unigram.

I'm not sure if other musical elements have a syntactic/grammatical aspect like functional harmony, but that's another question.

Answer (score 2):

My knee-jerk reaction is to suggest the [second of Bernstein's Norton Lectures at Harvard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_fxB6yrDVo), where he discusses musical syntax and makes correlations between musical objects and linguistic phonemes, morphemes, and the like. (I admit I can't remember if he touches on uni-grams, bi-grams, etc.)

More apt still might be Lerdahl and Jackendoff's *A Generative Theory of Tonal Music*. Jackendoff himself is a linguist, and although I again don't believe they reference uni-grams or bi-grams, they clearly do make connections between linguistic structure and musical structure.